# Xml Shredding .Value Singleton

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am querying an `Xml` column in SQL Server 2012.

When moving the path to the `.value` method the results are not returning all the `element` instances!

```
,c.value('(*/*/Visitors/Visitor/@Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Visitor
,c.value('(*/*/Senders/Sender/@Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As Sender
```

I originally was using the `nodes` method, but the `Wildcard` is killing performance

```
CROSS APPLY c.nodes('*') dd(d) 
OUTER APPLY d.nodes(Visitors/Visitor) As ee(e)
OUTER APPLY d.nodes('Senders/Sender') ff(f)
```

Now I know I can get the correct results with something like (below) but is there a way to return all the element results by using the path in the `.value` method without declaring 3 singletons, or is the `.nodes` method the only way of returning multiple element instances?

Thanks!

```
,c.value('(*/*/Visitors/Visitor/@Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Visitor
,c.value('(*/*/Visitors/Visitor/@Name)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Visitor2
,c.value('(*/*/Visitors/Visitor/@Name)[3]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') AS Visitor3     
,c.value('(*/*/Senders/Sender/@Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As Sender
,c.value('(*/*/Senders/Sender/@Name)[2]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As Sender2    
,c.value('(*/*/Senders/Sender/@Name)[3]', 'NVARCHAR(50)') As Sender3
```

Comment: `.value()` will only return **a single value** - if you need to enumerate a list of nodes, use `.nodes()` - that's what it's there for! But please - don't use `.nodes(*)` - that's just bad coding...

Comment: Yea I took it out of the .nodes(), thanks! Again  Move your comment to a question, that answered my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `.value()` will only return a single value by definition.

If you need to enumerate a list of nodes, use `.nodes()` - that's what it's there for.

But please avoid using `.nodes(*)` - that's just a killer for performance - you need to be as specific with your XPath in the `.nodes()` call

Answer (score 1):

You can select the elements you want from the nodes of the XML type:

```
declare @x as xml = 
  '<notes>' + 
    '<note>' + 
      '<to>ToP1</to>' +      
      '<Msg>Some Msg</Msg>' +
    '</note>' +
    '<note>' + 
      '<to>ToP2</to>' + 
  '<Msg>Some Msg</Msg>' +
    '</note>' +
  '</notes>';

select  Col1.value('(./to)[1]', 'char(10)' )  from @x.nodes('/notes/note') as x(Col1)
```